# searchable and able to sleelct all options in Django

Tags: django, forms

How can I make a form that I can do these with:

1_ seaerchable choice field like cities.

2_a button that make me able to select all of cities.

Comment: you want to search in the database?

Comment: no seaech for options. Like cities. for example the form has a field named city that has 1000 city. I want be able to search to choice a given city.

Comment: 1000 cities where exactly do you want to look for them?

Comment: select option tags in html